# How to save cookies in browser using GO + REACT?

Tags: reactjs, go, react-router, mux

I created a login page using **react over Go rest-API** but I found that **Browser** did not save cookie established in the login phase. I tried a number of similar issues solved over stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.
-- I wish anyone can help me resolve that issue

GO - Backend

```
func main(){
    HandleRequests()
}

func HandleRequests(){
    r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    r.HandleFunc("/login", Middleware(Login)).Methods("POST")
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(r)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", handler))
}

func Middleware(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })

}

func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    /*
        Compare Both User Name && Password
        READ - BODY
        Create New JWT
     */
    cookie := &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "jwt",
        Value:    token,
        Expires:  time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 60),
        HttpOnly: true,
    }

    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)

    respondWithJson(w, http.StatusOK, struct {
        Ok string `json:"ok"`
    }{
        Ok: "Success, Welcome back our friend !",
    })
}

func respondWithJson(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, payload interface{}) {
    response, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    w.Write(response)
}
```

REACT - Router - Frontend
React Runs over, http://localhost:3000

```
import React, { SyntheticEvent, useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
    const[username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const[password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const[redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)

    const submit = async (e : SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await fetch('http://localhost:8081/login', {
            method : 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,               
                password
            }),
            credentials:'include'
        });
        setRedirect(true);
    }
    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to = "/"/>;
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
            <input type="text" className="form-control"  placeholder="Username" required
                onChange = {e => setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required
                onChange = {e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <div className="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" /> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    );
};
```

Comment: The cookie path defaults to the request path, `/login`.  To access the cookie other paths, set the path to `/`:  `cookie := &http.Cookie{Path: "/", ...}`.

Comment: still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Browser can't save cookie because HttpOnly options is true.
If you want to save cookies to client browser, set your HttpOnly option  false.
but this is not safe to defend XSS attack.

```
cookie := &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "jwt",
    Value:    token,
    Expires:  time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 60),
    HttpOnly: false,
}
```

[Restrict access to cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)

Answer (score 0):

To include de Cookie generated by Go in the Request to your server the required code is:

```
cookie := &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "jwt",
    Value:    token,
    Expires:  time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 60),
    HttpOnly: true,
    Secure: true,
    SameSite: http.SameSiteNoneMode, // if you pretend to enable cross-site
}
```

Note: HttpOnly, Secure and SameSite is required.